# Django Admin looking for field that does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.8, python3, SQLite.

I had a model with a foreign key that referenced another model.  I updated the model to remove that foreign key completely and replaced it with a many-to-many key that referenced a different table.  I ran makemigrations and then ran the actual migration without errors.  However, when I go into admin and try to add a row to that table I get the following error:

```
Exception Type:     FieldError

Exception Value:    

Unknown field(s) (TheOneIDeleted) specified for TableIChanged. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class TableIChangedAdmin.
```

Why is there still a reference to the deleted field after the migration?  More importantly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have updated your models.py, but haven't updated the model admin in your admin.py.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  admin.py still contained a reference to the old field.